# World of Warcraft-Wine-low fps

Tags: wine

I've recently started to use Linux, and elementary OS and I've to say that it's great, everything works really nice, just have to get used to it. But I have one problem which makes me upset. I've installed Wine and tried to use my only 1 game which I have on laptop, and it runs, however not so fine as it is mentioned on Wine forums. I'm using an Acer 5755g which isn't the best for that game, but should run it on low settings really nice. Although im getting around 8-25FPS on Wine, is it a normal situation, or maybe i have some bad settings on elementary OS ?? For example on Win8.1 im getting like 30-50fps.

All the best and waiting for some help

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Which game, which display drivers, etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about elementary

Answer (score 1):

### A primer on how Wine works

As it name states, "Wine Is Not an Emulator". Wine doesn't create a Windows environment that .exes can live in: it relies on the use of fake libraries to *trick* .exes into thinking they're talking with Windows, when really it's just the Linux kernel in disguise. As such, it will be faster than an emulator (ie, Virtualbox) but may still be slower than Windows itself.
**The fact that your game runs slower is probably a normal behaviour, but you may be able to configure it to run better.**

### A few hints:

1. Update your Nvidia drivers (you seem to have an **NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M**).
2. Use OpenGL (probably better FPS but lower graphics quality) with your game.
3. Look up your game in the [Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/), as they may already have a solution to your low frame rates.

### How can we help you further?

- Give us your configuration, not just the model of your laptop.
- Give us more details on your problem (the name of your game, which version of elementary OS you are running...)

Comment: Well, thanks for reply altough I've already checked the Wine Application Database, and wow is at Platinum/Gold rank, which basicly means it runs flawlessly. I've Nvidia GeForce 540M, installed driver ver. 344, which is pretty new. And about OpenGL I've already tried that option and it helped, because I'd 1-10 fps before. I'm a linux newbie, if you give me some terminal code list I will be able to bring all required information.